# How to Sum from DataTable Multiple Columns Total in Repeater Footer row in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datatable

How to Add Total sum of these Columns and Repeater footer show each column Sum value ?

```
dataTable.Columns.Add("Meter", typeof(object));
dataTable.Columns.Add("tank_name", typeof(object));
dataTable.Columns.Add("OpeningBalance", typeof(object));
dataTable.Columns.Add("IN", typeof(object)); 
dataTable.Columns.Add("OUT", typeof(object));
dataTable.Columns.Add("ClosingBalance", typeof(object)); 
dataTable.Columns.Add("StartTemperature", typeof(object)); 
dataTable.Columns.Add("EndTemperature", typeof(object));
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, include the DDL for the data and a simple example with the expected results.Also... I have formatted both queries but are showing the same query, so, I think there is an erratum in your first version.

Comment: @CodeMan  openingBalance column  10 Rows and Out column 5 rows data i want  to add total in footer

Comment: @CodeMan must be from DataTable Sum for multiple Columns

Comment: `int total = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Sum(r => r.Field<int>("OpeningBalance"));`